# SQL query for multiple tables using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Need help with SQL query - my query at the moment works with two tables I want to add third table, but i have no idea how to do that, I tried many times but it gives error...

I will try to show all my code as more acurate:

**SQL QUERY**

```
$sql = "SELECT main.nid, main.title FROM {node} AS main
                    LEFT JOIN {localizernode} AS lang ON main.nid = lang.nid 
                    WHERE main.type = 'drug' AND main.title LIKE '%s%%' AND lang.language = '%s' AND main.status = 1 
                    ORDER BY main.title ASC";

$result = db_query($sql);
while ($product = db_fetch_object($result)) {
// build up the list
$product_list .= '<li>'.$product->title.'</li>';
}
```

*this QUERY grabs all data from table **NODE** based on website language where type is drug. And give me a list of all items in side that table, ordering by title*

**Table "node":**

**nid | vid | type | title | status**

9 | 9 | drug | Title 1 | 1

15 | 15 | drug | Title 2 | 1

---

**Table "content_type_drug" which I want to use/include in QUERY looks like:**

**vid  |  nid  |  value  |  image_title**

9 | 9 | Text value | imagename.jpg

15 | 15 | Text value5 | imagename3.jpg

What I want it to grab from "content_type_drug" the following values: "value", "image_title" and display them in the above list:

```
$result = db_query($sql);
    while ($product = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    // build up the list
    $product_list .= '<li>'.$product->title.$product->value.$product->image.'</li>';
    }
```

**I am looking for help, and not for FULL solution, please give me any ideas.**

Comment: What is related field in content_type_drug and to which table it relates

Comment: nid and vid is the only related

Comment: i dont understand. please tell clearly. If the problem you are facing is that of same field names in multiple tables you could use alias like `SELECT main.id AS main_id, lang.id AS lang_id .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand that you need to join three tables. So query will be

```
$sql = "SELECT main.nid, main.title, ctd.value,ctd.image_title FROM {node} AS main
        LEFT JOIN {localizernode} AS lang ON main.nid = lang.nid 
        INNER JOIN {content_type_drug} ctd ON main.vid = ctd.vid 
        WHERE main.type = 'drug' AND main.title LIKE '%s%%' 
        AND lang.language = '%s' AND main.status = 1  ORDER BY main.title ASC";
```

I am assuming that vid and nid are foreign keys. You can replace this clause with your foreign keys

Comment: Ok i guess this will do! But how will I grab info from third table and use it?

Comment: Get into columns list like ctd.value,ctd.image_title. I have updated query. You can access it like other columns

Answer (score 1):

To add a new table, you just need to add another join.

```
LEFT JOIN {content_type_drug} AS drug ON drug.vid = main.vid
```

So your full query will look like:

```
SELECT main.nid, main.title, drug.value, drug.image_title FROM {node} AS main
                LEFT JOIN {localizernode} AS lang ON main.nid = lang.nid 
                LEFT JOIN {content_type_drug} AS drug ON drug.vid = main.vid 
                WHERE main.type = 'drug' AND main.title LIKE '%s%%' AND lang.language = '%s' AND main.status = 1 
                ORDER BY main.title ASC
```

Hope this helps :)